# ¿En donde se programa un botón dentro del Navigation Drawer en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, navigation-drawer

He estado buscando información acerca de cual es el apartado en donde se deben programar los botones dentro de los fragmentos del Navigation Drawer, esto debido a que me genera por defecto dos apartados. El "GalleryFragment" y "GalleryViewModel"

Comment: Hola, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.